# Airflow running python files fails due to python: can't open file

Tags: python, docker, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a folder tree like this in my `project`

- project

  - dags
  - python_scripts
  - libraries
  - docker-compose.yml
  - Dockerfile
  - docker_resources

I create an airflow service in a docker container with:

```
dockerfile

#Base image
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.1

#Impersonate
USER root

#Los automatically thrown to the I/O strem and not buffered.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/libraries"

WORKDIR /
#Add docker source files to the docker machine
ADD ./docker_resources ./docker_resources
#Install libraries and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
RUN pip install --user psycopg2-binary
RUN pip install -r docker_resources/requirements.pip


Docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    container_name: "postgres"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  webserver:
    build: .
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ./libraries:/libraries
      - ./python_scripts:/python_scripts
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: webserver
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
  scheduler:
    build: .
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ./logs:/usr/local/airflow/logs
    ports:
      - "8793:8793"
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-scheduler.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
```

My dag folder has a tutorial with:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
# The DAG object; we'll need this to instantiate a DAG
from airflow import DAG
# Operators; we need this to operate!
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
# These args will get passed on to each operator
# You can override them on a per-task basis during operator initialization
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'email': ['xxx@xxx.com '],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'schedule_interval': '@daily',
}

dag = DAG(
    'Tutorial',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG with production tables',
    catchup=False
)

task_1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='my_task',
    bash_command='python /python_scripts/my_script.py',
    dag=dag,
)
```

I tried changing `bash_command='python /python_scripts/my_script.py',`
for:

- `bash_command='python python_scripts/my_script.py',`
- `bash_command='python ~/../python_scripts/my_script.py',`
- `bash_command='python ~/python_scripts/my_script.py',`

And all of them fails. I tried them because `BashOperator` run the command in a `tmp` folder.
If I get in the machine, and run `ls` command I find the file, under `python_scripts`.
Even if I run `python /python_scripts/my_script.py` from `/usr/local/airflow`it works.

The error is always:

> INFO - python: can't open file

I searched and people solved the issue with absolute paths, but I can't fix it.

**Edit**
If in the dockerfile I add `ADD ./ ./` below `WORKDIR /`
and I delete these volumes from `docker-compose.yml`:

```
 1. ./libraries:/libraries

 2. ./python_scripts:/python_scripts
```

The error is not file not found, is libraries not found. `Import module error`. Which is an improvement, but doesn't make sense cause `PYTHONPATH` is defined to have `/libraries` folder.

Makes more sense the volumes that the `ADD` statement, because I need to have the changes applied into the code instantly into the docker.

**Edit 2:**
Volumes are mounted but no file is inside the container folders, this is why is not able to find the files. When run Add ./ ./ the folder has the files cause there add all the files inside the folder. Despite it doesn't work due libraries are not found neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue, I discard all previous work, and restart `DOCKERFILE` using an `UBUNTU` base image, and not `puckel/docker-airflow` image which is based in `python:3.7-slim-buster`.

I don't use any other user that its not root know.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
bash_command='python /usr/local/airflow/python_scripts/my_script.py'
```

And you have to check if the folder have the good permissions (access and execute for your user)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried, and doesn't work. It makes sense, cause volumes for the python_scripts folder is not dependent from /usr/local/airflow.

Now I am running a recursive permision change to test if its something related with permisions.

Comment: Just finished recursive permision change. And it doesnt works. I run 'chmod -R 700 /' inside docker machine.